# Unable acess auth user in Laravel 5.3 API ROUTE

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Here is my code in routes, controller.

api routes:

`api.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
   Route::get('/get-user','ApiController@getUserInfo');
});
```

Controller:

`ApiController.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class ApiControllerextends Controller{

     public function getUserInfo(){
         $user =Auth::user();dd($user);
     }

 }
```

Comment: The method you trying to access in your routes isnt the one you want. it should be getHashtag() instead.

Comment: actually the code i pasted is wrong can u please check once@FaizKhan

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Simply make your controller class read:

```
class ApiController extends Controller {}
```

instead of the current one:

```
class ApiControllerextends Controller {}
```

---

Note that the controller you are referring to in your `api.php` (ApiController) does not exist.

Instead of this,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
    Route::get('/get-user','ApiController@getUserInfo');
});
```

Do this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
    Route::get('/get-user','ApiControllerextends@getUserInfo');
});
```

Because the defined controller you have is `ApiControllerextends`; not `ApiController`.

Also, your controller method has an error;

Instead of this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class ApiControllerextends Controller{

     public function getUserInfo(){
         $user =Auth::user();dd($user);
     }

 }
```

You should have:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class ApiControllerextends extends Controller{

     public function getUserInfo(){
         $user =Auth::user();dd($user);
     }

 }
```

or this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class ApiController extends Controller{

     public function getUserInfo(){
         $user =Auth::user();dd($user);
     }

 }
```

Because you actually need to extend the inbuilt laravel `Controller` class by extending it using *extends*.

Using the guidelines above should help understand and resolve the challenge you are facing.

*... more details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#basic-controllers.)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your Api controller from controller, like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class ApiController extends Controller{

     public function getUserInfo(){
         $user =Auth::user();
         dd($user);
     }

 }
```

The route will look like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
       Route::get('/get-user','ApiController@getUserInfo');
});
```